# Combination Functional/Load/Stress Testing Website Libraries Python

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium, locust, funkload

I have the need to scale up some testing efforts for web application.  I'm most familiar with using selenium (with python bindings) for functional testing amongst other things.  Now that I need to also do concurrent load/stress testing I think I need to take different approach.  I like the look of locust, but I'm not sure how to integrate the functional test requirements as well.  The basic test outline for an individual user is this:

1. login to site with credentials
2. "click" relevant angular elements to navigate the site
3. "click" and initiate download of various reports

Ideally, I could scale this with 10-50-100 concurrent users and get a log file with results (times, failures, etc.)

Any best practices tips from the frequently unsung test heros would be sincerely appreciated!

EDIT:

I realize this is a bit non-standard.  Just the nature of what I am trying replicate with new relic running the background for analytics.  Currently, I'm trying to figure out if Selenium can be combined with Locust in an appropriate way.

Comment: It's kind a weird wish to combine all these test types. I recommend you to use `selenium` and `jmeter` separately for particular test type

Comment: Agreed on the combination being a bit odd.  But I'm not quite sure how else to do it, since the performance issues I am try to identify are related to concurrent use of this functionality.  Thanks for your recs though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that your first choice was Locust. The main strength of Locust that it is the Python code based tool and you can do there almost everything else what you can do in pure Python. 
if you are looking for some functional testing aspect, you can even do it in integration with your load tests with default Python assertions library. 
Check this article, it should give you some thoughts on how to make functional checks within your Locust performance tests using Python:
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/locust-assertions-a-complete-user-manual